# Audio files won't stop playing when I go to next item in list

Tags: java

Here is my code:

```
public APJMenu createMenu(String menuLabel, String[] menuItems) {
    // create menu item with passed in title
    APJMenu menu = new APJMenu(menuLabel, getSoundFileName(menuLabel),
            this.audioSourceType);
    
    APJMenuItem menuItem;
    for (int i = 0; i < menuItems.length; i++) {
        menuItem = new APJMenuItem(menuItems[i],
                getSoundFileName(menuItems[i]), audioSourceType);
        
        menuItem.setEnabled(true);
        menuItem.addActionListener(this);
        menuItem.addMenuKeyListener(this);
        menuItem.setActionCommand(menuItems[i]);
        
        menu.add(menuItem);
    }

    return menu;
}
```

This is what the Main program basically does. This is where all of the audio files are added to the menus which enables audio playback. However, there is also a referenced JAR file that communicates with the program and that actually reads in the text and makes the calls to play the corresponding audio file. If you run the program, you will generate a menu that plays audio as you navigate the item list.

**APJMenuItem class**

```
// Referenced classes of package enhancedWidgets: APComponent, APComponentGenerics, APJFrame

public class APJMenuItem extends JMenuItem
    implements APComponent, MouseListener, MenuKeyListener {

    public APJMenuItem(String label) {
        super(label);
        type = DEFAULT_SOUND_TYPE;
        visuals_enabled = true;
        init(soundTypes.Sound.SoundType.Spearcon, label, null);
    }

    public APJMenuItem(String label, String filename, soundTypes.Sound.SoundType type) {
        super(label);
        this.type = DEFAULT_SOUND_TYPE;
        visuals_enabled = true;
        init(type, label, filename);
    }

    private void init(soundTypes.Sound.SoundType type, String label, String filename) {
        this.type = type;
        switch($SWITCH_TABLE$soundTypes$Sound$SoundType()[type.ordinal()]) {
        case 5: // '\005'
            sound = new Spearcon(label, null);
            break;

        case 1: // '\001'
        case 3: // '\003'
            sound = new AuditoryIcon(new File(filename));
            break;

        case 2: // '\002'
        case 4: // '\004'
        default:
            sound = null;
            break;
        }
        addMouseListener(this);
        addMenuKeyListener(this);
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        super.setText(text);
        if(type == null)
            type = DEFAULT_SOUND_TYPE;
        init(type, text, null);
    }

    public void setFile(String filename) {
        init(soundTypes.Sound.SoundType.SoundFile, getText(), filename);
    }

    public void findSoundListener() {
        APComponentGenerics.findSoundListener(listener, this);
        sound.setSoundListener(listener);
    }

    public void updateSoundListener(APJFrame frame) {
        listener = APComponentGenerics.updateSoundListener(frame);
        sound.setSoundListener(listener);
    }

    public boolean hasSoundListener() {
        return APComponentGenerics.hasSoundListener(listener);
    }

    public APComponent.ComponentType getComponentType() {
        return APComponent.ComponentType.menuitem;
    }

    public boolean isAPComponent() {
        return true;
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent mouseevent) {
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent mouseevent) {
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent mouseevent) {
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        sound.stop();
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        if(!hasSoundListener())
            findSoundListener();
        (new Thread(sound)).start();
    }

    public void menuKeyPressed(MenuKeyEvent e) {
        if(isArmed() && !sound.isStopped())
            sound.stop();
    }

    public void menuKeyReleased(MenuKeyEvent e) {
        if(isArmed()) {
            if(!hasSoundListener())
                findSoundListener();
            (new Thread(sound)).start();
        }
    }

    public void menuKeyTyped(MenuKeyEvent menukeyevent) {
    }

    public void setVisualsEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        visuals_enabled = enabled;
    }

    public boolean isVisualsEnabled() {
        return visuals_enabled;
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        if(isVisualsEnabled())
            super.paintComponent(g);
    }

    static int[] $SWITCH_TABLE$soundTypes$Sound$SoundType() {
        $SWITCH_TABLE$soundTypes$Sound$SoundType;
        if($SWITCH_TABLE$soundTypes$Sound$SoundType == null) goto _L2; else goto _L1
_L1:
        return;
_L2:
        JVM INSTR pop ;
        int ai[] = new int[soundTypes.Sound.SoundType.values().length];
        try {
            ai[soundTypes.Sound.SoundType.AuditoryIcon.ordinal()] = 1;
        }
        catch(NoSuchFieldError _ex) { }
        try {
            ai[soundTypes.Sound.SoundType.Earcon.ordinal()] = 2;
        }
        catch(NoSuchFieldError _ex) { }
        try {
            ai[soundTypes.Sound.SoundType.Other.ordinal()] = 6;
        }
        catch(NoSuchFieldError _ex) { }
        try {
            ai[soundTypes.Sound.SoundType.SoundFile.ordinal()] = 3;
        }
        catch(NoSuchFieldError _ex) { }
        try {
            ai[soundTypes.Sound.SoundType.SoundScape.ordinal()] = 4;
        }
        catch(NoSuchFieldError _ex) { }
        try {
            ai[soundTypes.Sound.SoundType.Spearcon.ordinal()] = 5;
        }
        catch(NoSuchFieldError _ex) { }
        return $SWITCH_TABLE$soundTypes$Sound$SoundType = ai;
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 0x77c71df3L;
    Sound sound;
    SoundListener listener;
    private static soundTypes.Sound.SoundType DEFAULT_SOUND_TYPE;
    soundTypes.Sound.SoundType type;
    private boolean visuals_enabled;
    private static int $SWITCH_TABLE$soundTypes$Sound$SoundType[];

    static  {
        DEFAULT_SOUND_TYPE = soundTypes.Sound.SoundType.Spearcon;
    }
}
```

**APJMenu class**

```
// Referenced classes of package enhancedWidgets:
//            APComponent, APComponentGenerics, APJMenuItem, APJFrame

public class APJMenu extends JMenu
    implements MouseListener, MenuListener, APComponent, MenuKeyListener {

    public APJMenu(String label) {
        super(label);
        listener = null;
        frame = null;
        visuals_enabled = true;
        init(soundTypes.Sound.SoundType.Spearcon, label, null);
    }

    public APJMenu(String label, String filename, soundTypes.Sound.SoundType type) {
        super(label);
        listener = null;
        frame = null;
        visuals_enabled = true;
        init(type, label, filename);
    }

    private void init(soundTypes.Sound.SoundType type, String label, String filename) {
        this.type = type;
        switch($SWITCH_TABLE$soundTypes$Sound$SoundType()[type.ordinal()]) {
        case 5: // '\005'
            sound = new Spearcon(label, null);
            break;

        case 1: // '\001'
        case 3: // '\003'
            sound = new AuditoryIcon(new File(filename));
            break;

        case 2: // '\002'
        case 4: // '\004'
        default:
            sound = null;
            break;
        }
        addMouseListener(this);
        addMenuListener(this);
    }

    public void findSoundListener() {
        APComponentGenerics.findSoundListener(listener, this);
        sound.setSoundListener(listener);
    }

    public void updateSoundListener() {
        findSoundListener();
    }

    public boolean hasSoundListener() {
        return APComponentGenerics.hasSoundListener(listener);
    }

    public void updateSoundListener(APJFrame frame) {
        listener = APComponentGenerics.updateSoundListener(frame);
        this.frame = frame;
        sound.setSoundListener(listener);
    }

    public void add(APJMenuItem menuItem) {
        super.add(menuItem);
        menuItem.updateSoundListener(frame);
        menuItem.addMenuKeyListener(this);
    }

    public void add(APJMenu menu) {
        super.add(menu);
        menu.updateSoundListener(frame);
    }

    public APComponent.ComponentType getComponentType() {
        return APComponent.ComponentType.menu;
    }

    public boolean isAPComponent() {
        return true;
    }

    public void menuCanceled(MenuEvent e) {
        if(!sound.isStopped())
            sound.stop();
    }

    public void menuDeselected(MenuEvent e) {
        if(!sound.isStopped())
            sound.stop();
    }

    public void menuSelected(MenuEvent e) {
        if(!hasSoundListener())
            findSoundListener();
        if(!sound.isStopped())
            sound.stop();
        (new Thread(sound)).start();
        (new Thread(sound)).start();
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent mouseevent) {
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent mouseevent) {
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent mouseevent) {
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        sound.stop();
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        if(!hasSoundListener())
            findSoundListener();
        (new Thread(sound)).start();
    }

    public void menuKeyPressed(MenuKeyEvent e) {
        if(!sound.isStopped())
            sound.stop();
    }

    public void menuKeyReleased(MenuKeyEvent menukeyevent) {
    }

    public void menuKeyTyped(MenuKeyEvent menukeyevent) {
    }

    public void setVisualsEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        visuals_enabled = enabled;
    }

    public boolean isVisualsEnabled() {
        return visuals_enabled;
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        if(isVisualsEnabled())
            super.paintComponent(g);
    }

    static int[] $SWITCH_TABLE$soundTypes$Sound$SoundType() {
        $SWITCH_TABLE$soundTypes$Sound$SoundType;
        if($SWITCH_TABLE$soundTypes$Sound$SoundType == null) goto _L2; else goto _L1
_L1:
        return;
_L2:
        JVM INSTR pop ;
        int ai[] = new int[soundTypes.Sound.SoundType.values().length];
        try {
            ai[soundTypes.Sound.SoundType.AuditoryIcon.ordinal()] = 1;
        }
        catch(NoSuchFieldError _ex) { }
        try {
            ai[soundTypes.Sound.SoundType.Earcon.ordinal()] = 2;
        }
        catch(NoSuchFieldError _ex) { }
        try {
            ai[soundTypes.Sound.SoundType.Other.ordinal()] = 6;
        }
        catch(NoSuchFieldError _ex) { }
        try {
            ai[soundTypes.Sound.SoundType.SoundFile.ordinal()] = 3;
        }
        catch(NoSuchFieldError _ex) { }
        try {
            ai[soundTypes.Sound.SoundType.SoundScape.ordinal()] = 4;
        }
        catch(NoSuchFieldError _ex) { }
        try {
            ai[soundTypes.Sound.SoundType.Spearcon.ordinal()] = 5;
        }
        catch(NoSuchFieldError _ex) { }
        return $SWITCH_TABLE$soundTypes$Sound$SoundType = ai;
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 0xf123a728L;
    Sound sound;
    SoundListener listener;
    APJFrame frame;
    soundTypes.Sound.SoundType type;
    private boolean visuals_enabled;
    private static int $SWITCH_TABLE$soundTypes$Sound$SoundType[];
}
```

**Sound class**

```
package soundTypes;

import soundServer.SoundListener;

public abstract class Sound
    implements Runnable {
    /* member class not found */
class SoundType {}


public Sound() {
}

public abstract void play();

public abstract void stop();

public abstract SoundType getSoundType();

public boolean isAuditoryIcon() {
    return false;
}

public boolean isEarcon() {
    return false;
}

public boolean isSoundFile() {
    return false;
}

public boolean isSoundScape() {
    return false;
}

public boolean isSpearcon() {
    return false;
}

public boolean isOther() {
    return false;
}

public abstract boolean isStopped();

public boolean isMenuSound(Sound s) {
    return s.isAuditoryIcon() || s.isEarcon() || s.isSpearcon();
}

public void setSoundListener(SoundListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}

protected SoundListener listener;
```

}

**SoundFile class**

```
package soundTypes;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import soundServer.StopWatch;

// Referenced classes of package soundTypes:
//            Sound

public class SoundFile extends Sound {

public SoundFile(File file) {
    stopped = true;
    continuous = false;
    gainControl = null;
    playFrequency = 1.0D;
    this.file = null;
    volume = 0.0D;
    second = false;
    initialize(file);
}

private void initialize(File file) {
    this.file = file;
    try {
        stream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
        AudioFormat format = stream.getFormat();
        if(format.getEncoding() != javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED) {
            format = new AudioFormat(javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, format.getSampleRate(), format.getSampleSizeInBits(), format.getChannels(), format.getFrameSize(), format.getFrameRate(), true);
            stream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(format, stream);
        }
        javax.sound.sampled.DataLine.Info info = new javax.sound.sampled.DataLine.Info(javax/sound/sampled/Clip, stream.getFormat(), (int)stream.getFrameLength() * format.getFrameSize());
        clip = (Clip)AudioSystem.getLine(info);
        try {
            gainControl = (FloatControl)clip.getControl(javax.sound.sampled.FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);
        }
        catch(IllegalArgumentException exception) {
            gainControl = null;
        }
    }
    catch(MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(LineUnavailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public long getClipLengthMS() {
    boolean wasOpen = clip.isOpen();
    if(!wasOpen)
        try {
            clip.open(stream);
        }
        catch(LineUnavailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    long length = clip.getMicrosecondLength();
    if(!wasOpen)
        clip.close();
    return length;
}

public void setVolume(double percent) {
    if(gainControl == null) {
        return;
    } else {
        volume = percent;
        float dB = (float)((Math.log(percent) / Math.log(10D)) * 20D);
        gainControl.setValue(dB);
        return;
    }
}

public void setContiuous(boolean continuous) {
    this.continuous = continuous;
    if(this.continuous)
        clip.loop(-1);
    else
        clip.loop(0);
}

public void play() {
    second = !second;
    if(!second)
        return;
    stopped = false;
    try {
        clip.stop();
        clip.close();
        initialize(file);
        clip.open(stream);
        clip.start();
    }
    catch(LineUnavailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    StopWatch watch = new StopWatch();
    watch.start();
    while(!stopped) ;
    clip.stop();
}

public void stop() {
    stopped = true;
}

public void run() {
    play();
}

public double getPlayFrequency() {
    return playFrequency;
}

public void setPlayFrequency(double playFrequency) {
    this.playFrequency = playFrequency;
}

public boolean isStopped() {
    return stopped;
}

public SoundFile clone() {
    SoundFile clone = new SoundFile(getFile());
    clone.setContiuous(continuous);
    clone.setPlayFrequency(playFrequency);
    clone.setVolume(volume);
    return clone;
}

public File getFile() {
    return file;
}

public Sound.SoundType getSoundType() {
    return Sound.SoundType.SoundFile;
}

public boolean isSoundFile() {
    return true;
}

public volatile Object clone()
    throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    return clone();
}

boolean stopped;
boolean continuous;
FloatControl gainControl;
Clip clip;
AudioInputStream stream;
double playFrequency;
File file;
double volume;
boolean second;
}
```

The issue I am having is whenever you go to the next item (audio file) in the menu, the previous audio file doesn't stop (I NEED IT TO STOP!). I literally have no idea how to fix this as I cannot edit the files inside the jar.
I have uploaded all of the files here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz9A-abBN69HSG1yRjFrWFNxQXc/view?usp=sharing

so that you can see what I'm talking about.

-

**KEY INFORMATION:**

> In order to run the Main program, you need to:
>
> - Run the file named "MenuDriver_SPT"
>
> To navigate the menu system within the application:
>
> - On a Mac - Hold down OPTION and press SPACE BAR
> - On a Windows - Hold down ALT and press SPACE BAR
>
> You then navigate the menu using the arrow keys

If you import the file system into eclipse, it should run without any problems.
Again the files are here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz9A-abBN69HSG1yRjFrWFNxQXc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Think about using a boolean variable to keep track of whether an audio file is playing...

boolean isPlaying;

Comment: Please edit your question (using the `edit` link below your question text) to include the code for the `APJMenuItem` class.  Questions need to be self-contained, so posting an entire project elsewhere is not considered a valid/complete question.

Comment: @VGR ok thanks. I went ahead and added the class files

Comment: I'm afraid your problem may be too broad in scope to be answered here.  It appears none of the classes you've posted so far are actually responsible for playing sound.  You might be able to find the responsible class by searching for "javax.sound" or "javax.media" in the code.